# How to find nth prime with complexity o(1)

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, primes

How to find nth prime number with complexity o(1)

Comment: Are you sure it's possible?  You can't even print the nth prime in constant time.

Comment: If you can do that _without_ first finding all possible primes, then the Maths Gods would like to hear from you.

Comment: [Testing for a prime is polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test), so it doesn't seem likely that you could find a particular prime faster than that.  If you could, then you should be able to do primality testing in constant time, too.

Comment: maybe you should take this question to mathoverflow.net

Comment: The simple answer is there is no way to do this. But if you will keep M prime numbers you can return Nth from them if N < M with complexity O(1), that will be solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this in O(1) would be an array of all prime numbers.  So, you'd only be able to support a certain number depending on your computer's memory.

**Edit:**

There might be some way to compute this involving a bunch of calculus, but that's beyond me :)

Comment: Are you sure you can search a number inside an array (of undefined length) in constant time? Don't think so... :-s

Comment: Why do you need to search?  nth prime number is nth index in array.  It's a pointer incrementation to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. In fact, you can't enumerate prime number without doing exhaustive search.

If you have a database with all prime numbers up to **n** you could search the **nth** prime number (up to **n**) in `o(log n)`.

Comment: So whats the best procedure to find nth prime number with least complexity?

Comment: -1: In fact you *can* find the n-th prime without doing exhaustive search. In fact, fast algorithms for pi(x) allow a technique similar to a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

To find the n-th prime in fixed time would imply that there's a reasonable formula for calculating pi(n) (return the n-th prime number). See http://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/p_n.html for preliminary discussion on this topic.